# Django apache+mod_wsgi openPanel virtualenv setup

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am deploying two django sites on apache with mod_wsgi. I have installed two virtualenvs:

```
/home/user/virtualenv1
/home/user/virtualenv2
```

Now my problem is configuring the wsgi apps to use these, for instance I have:

```
/var/www/djangosite1
/var/www/djangosite1/project1/wsgi.py

/var/www/djangosite2
/var/www/djangosite2/project2/wsgi.py
```

My apache is configured via openPanel so I have my VirtualHosts included like this:

**/etc/apache2/openpanel.d/project1.com.inc/django.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName project1

WSGIDaemonProcess project1 user=user group=www-data processes=2 threads=25 python-path=/home/user/virtualenv1/lib/python2.6/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup project1
</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/apache2/openpanel.d/project2.com.inc/django.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName project2

WSGIDaemonProcess project2 user=user group=www-data processes=2 threads=25 python-path=/home/user/virtualenv2/lib/python2.6/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup project2
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I restart apache:

```
service apache2 reload
```

Which doesn't give me any errors, next I tail the error log and visit my project.com

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Which gives me this error

```
ImportError: No module named south
```

When I install south on my system (not in a virtualenv) all works, but offcourse the idea is not to contaminate the system but use a seperate virtual env for each site.

I think I'm missing the obvious..

Comment: If you `activate` a virtualenv and `runserver` do each of the sites work?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/404079/django-apache-mod-wsgi-with-virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need check your current south path on virtualenv and add to your sys.path previously.

Comment: shouldn't it be enough to add the path to /home/user/virtualenv1/lib/python2.6/site-packages where south is installed

Comment: >>> import south
<module 'south' from '/home/user/lib/python2.6/site-packages/south/__init__.pyc'>

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling your virtualenv in the wsgi file rather than adding site-packages in the vhost.

Add the following to the top of your wsgi files.

```
# Start the correct virtualenv
activate_this = '/home/user/virtualenv1/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

(I'm not sure if this is the official way to do things but its certainly something I have had working many times.)